# Making drop-off points on a CAN bus

Tags: connector, cables, can

I want to connect some ATmega328P µC's to a CAN bus by using MCP2551 & MCP2515 ic's. I want to use some Cat5e 4x2 twisted pairs cable.

How do I make the actual drop off points? Do I just cut the cable in two, twine the cut wires together and solder them to the MCP2551 pins?

Comment: I found this (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/166833/can-bus-connector-issue) which points somewhat to the "yes" answer on my question. Though still not really sure. Anyone?

Comment: On the topic of creating CAN "stubs": https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/292651/effect-of-splices-on-120-%ce%a9-twisted-pair-cable-impedance-a-k-a-correct-way-to-att